# pod spec lint error: "unexpected '@' in program"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, lint

I am creating a podspec file for an open-source project I created, and I am utilizing Apple's UIImage+ImageEffects.h/.m for a blur effect, and inside there, they use the new `@import Accelerate;` syntax versus `#import <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>`. When I run `pod spec lint SFSCollectionMenu.podspec`, I receive the error:

- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  SFSCollectionMenu/UIImage+ImageEffects.h:96:1: error: unexpected '@' in program

Does the CocoaPods platform not like the new modules syntax? I'm relatively new to CocoaPods so there very well could be something I'm missing.  I followed Nils Hayat's blog for creating a simple pod (which fit my scenario perfectly -- nothing outlandish), http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/07/21/how-to-open-source-objective-c-code/, and receive this error in his section about verifying the pod via lint.

Here's relevant lines from podspec file:

`s.source_files = 'SFSCollectionMenuController.*{h,m}', 'SFSCircleLayout.*{h,m}', 'SFSMenuCell.*{h,m}', 'UIImage+ImageEffects.*{h,m}'`

`s.frameworks = 'Accelerate', 'QuartzCore', 'AVFoundation'`

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Modules are turned on by default in Xcode, can you test whether adding `spec.compiler_flags = "-fmodules"` to turn on modules in your generated library fixes this?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @orta. I added `s.compiler_flags = '-fmodules'` right after the `s.frameworks...` line in the podspec file, ran lint, and it seems to have fixed it. Now I just get a "WARN | Comments must be deleted", but I'm sure that can be handled separately. Thank you!

Comment: I think modules are the default in new projects with the new SDK

Comment: Yea, I believe you're right. Modules are ON in my project's Build Settings (started project using Xcode 5 betas where it's ON by default), that's why I was wondering why it failed.

Comment: Great, as modules are probably the future we should think about this, any chance you can write an issue on the cocoapods github?